# Poisson process for queuing problem

Tags: self-study, poisson-process

I posted it incorrectly on a different thread so I'm reposting it here.

I'm working on a problem and would love to get any advice - patients come into a clinic according to a Poisson process with time parameter 10 minutes starting from 9 am until 4pm when the clinic stops admitting new patients. There are 3 doctors each of whose time spent with each patient in uniformly distributed between 5 and 20 minutes. I'm running simulation for answering:

1. how many patients came,
2. how many had to wait for a doctor,
3. their average waiting time,
4. time the office closed.

For question 1 I did the following:

```
 > theta <- rexp(1, 10)
 > theta
 [1] 0.08533904
 > patients <- rpois(1, theta*420)
 > patients
 [1] 43
```

Where I am stuck is the rest of the problem. I am simulating a doctor's time spent with each patient as the following:

```
> theta.doc <- runif(1, 5, 20)
> theta.doc
[1] 6.474338
```

I am unclear how to proceed from here to answer questions 2, 3, and 4. As I understand, my simulation shows that each doctor spends about 6.5 minutes with each patient. How do I link the number of patients who come into clinic (43) and each doctor's time with each patient (6.5 min) to simulate answers for 2, 3, and 4?

Comment: Using R to answer this question looks a bit difficult. The best software for this question would be ARENA software, i used it and it works.